# How to create the singleton class in ios?

Tags: ios4

I want to know the porper way to create the singleton class.Currently I am doing in the following way.
In the .h file I am declaring the instance of the class in the following way.

```
@interface GlobalMethods : NSObject
{
}
+ (GlobalMethods *)sharedInstance;
```

And in the .m file I did the code in the following way.

```
@implementation GlobalMethods
- (id)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self)
{
    //Custom Intialization
}

return self;
}

+ (GlobalMethods *)sharedInstance
{
     static GlobalMethods *sharedInstance = nil;
     @synchronized(self)
     {
         if (sharedInstance == NULL)
         {
              sharedInstance = [[GlobalMethods alloc] init];
         }
      return sharedInstance;
 }
```

}

Comment: Strictly speaking there is no way of creating a singleton when using arc. You can create a shared object, which is very similar. Are you using Arc?

Comment: Also you might want to look at dispatch_once https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_once instead of @synchronised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we can create only one instance from that singleton class.
>  take a
>   look at this page for more information with code :

```
    http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/
```